# Extending a ruby class (hash) with new function (recursive_merge)

Tags: ruby

If I want to recursively merge 2 hashes, I can do so with the following function:

```
def recursive_merge(a,b)
  a.merge(b) {|key,a_item,b_item| recursive_merge(a_item,b_item) }
end
```

This works great, in that I can now do:

```
aHash = recursive_merge(aHash,newHash)
```

But I'd like to add this as a self-updating style method similar to `merge!`. I can add in the returning function:

```
class Hash
  def recursive_merge(newHash)
    self.merge { |key,a_item,b_item| a_item.recursive_merge(b_item) }
  end
end
```

But am not sure how to re-create the `bang` function that updates the original object without association.

```
class Hash
  def recursive_merge!(newHash)
    self.merge { |key,a_item,b_item| a_item.recursive_merge(b_item) }
    # How do I set "self" to this new hash?
  end
end
```

**edit** example as per comments.

```
h={:a=>{:b => "1"}
h.recursive_merge!({:a=>{:c=>"2"})
 => {:a=>{:b=>"1", :c="2"}}
```

The regular merge results in `:b=>"1"` being overwritten by `:c="2"`

Comment: Did you try `self.merge! { |key,a_item,b_item| a_item.recursive_merge!(b_item) }`

Comment: It help us if you gave a few hash examples and expected outcomes.  `merge` by default will replace values with the same keys so unless you plan to do something differently the block/recursive approach this might not make sense?

Comment: I might guess he means if the values are hashes, then recursively merge those values, rather than simply overwrite one with the other.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh blindly obvious - I didn't. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `merge!` rather than attempt to update `self`. I don't believe it makes sense to use merge! anywhere but at the top level, so I wouldn't call the bang version recursively. Instead, use merge! at the top level, and call the non-bang method recursively.

It may also be wise to check both values being merged are indeed hashes, otherwise you may get an exception if you attempt to recursive_merge on a non-hash object.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Hash
  def recursive_merge(other)
    self.merge(other) { |key, value1, value2| value1.is_a?(Hash) && value2.is_a?(Hash) ? value1.recursive_merge(value2) : value2}
  end

  def recursive_merge!(other)
    self.merge!(other) { |key, value1, value2| value1.is_a?(Hash) && value2.is_a?(Hash) ? value1.recursive_merge(value2) : value2}
  end
end


h1 = { a: { b:1, c:2 }, d:1 }
h2 = { a: { b:2, d:4 }, d:2 }
h3 = { d: { b:1, c:2 } }


p h1.recursive_merge(h2) # => {:a=>{:b=>2, :c=>2, :d=>4}, :d=>2}
p h1.recursive_merge(h3) #  => {:a=>{:b=>1, :c=>2}, :d=>{:b=>1, :c=>2}}

p h1.recursive_merge!(h2) # => {:a=>{:b=>2, :c=>2, :d=>4}, :d=>2}
p h1 # => {:a=>{:b=>2, :c=>2, :d=>4}, :d=>2}
```

If you have a specific reason to fully merge in place, possibly for speed, you can experiment with making the second function call itself recursively, rather than delegate the recursion to the first function. Be aware that may produce unintended side effects if the hashes store shared objects.

Example:

```
h1 = { a:1, b:2 }
h2 = { a:5, c:9 }
h3 = { a:h1, b:h2 }
h4 = { a:h2, c:h1 }

p h3.recursive_merge!(h4)
# Making recursive calls to recursive_merge
# => {:a=>{:a=>5, :b=>2, :c=>9}, :b=>{:a=>5, :c=>9}, :c=>{:a=>1, :b=>2}}
# Making recursive calls to recursive_merge!
# => {:a=>{:a=>5, :b=>2, :c=>9}, :b=>{:a=>5, :c=>9}, :c=>{:a=>5, :b=>2, :c=>9}}
```

As you can see, the second (shared) copy of h1 stored under the key :c is updated to reflect the merge of h1 and h2 under the key :a. This may be surprising and unwanted. Hence why I recommend using `recursive_merge` for the recursion, and not `recursive_merge!`.

Comment: Ah ok - makes sense. Why the checks in the recursive function though? I tested with my use case without the checks and it works well too and wondering what conditions you are catering for with those `is_a?(Hash)`'s? Marked as correct.

Comment: If you re-use a key, but both values are not  hashes, it will throw an exception.

Comment: To further clarify, the `recursive_merge` method is only defined on `Hash`, and so you can only recurse on hash instances. If the values are `Fixnum`s, as in my example, you'll get en exception: undefined method 'recursive_merge' for Fixnum.